# Grouping counties into provinces, st_exteriorring(MultiPolygon)

Tags: postgis

I loaded into PostGIS (to be used in QGIS and web) a shapefile containing *areas* of a country. These *areas* are grouped in *zones*. I'm trying to create the shapes of these zones (and later an additional level).

The naive approach was:

```
create table eric_z as
  select
    z.id,
    z.name,
    st_multi(st_union(a.geom)) as geom,
    count(*)
  from geo_a a
    inner join geo_z z on a."Z_id" = z.id
  group by z.id, z.name;
```

This works but for some areas where the borders are not exactly matching, I'm getting inner points like this:

[image: areas with annoying lines within the area]

I then thought about using st_exteriorring. Since this produces outer LineString, I used st_makepolygon to get full shapes. The issue would not be fully visible in the screenshot below with just lines.

```
create table eric_z2 as
  select
    z.id,
    z.name,
    st_makepolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(st_union(a.geom))) as geom,
    count(*)
  from geo_a a
    inner join geo_z z on a."ZS_id" = z.id
  group by z.id, z.name
```

This seems to work at first but as predicted in comments by @ThingumaBob, it can be tricky because `st_exteriorring` can have issues with multipolygons. The result is that some areas suddenly become null:

[image: Zones 723 and 717 are null after st_exteriorring]

@Thingumabob suggested to use st_dump to get the individual lines, exteriorring them and then turn it back to polygons. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Something that does work but that I find awfully dirty is to enlarge the polygons by a short distance and then shrink them again. This actually does what I want but I'd feel dirty committing that code into posterity... :(

```
st_buffer(st_buffer(st_multi(st_union(a.geom)), 0.00001), -0.00001)
```

Any better suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your problem is the table geo_a is multipolygons you need to use st_dump to return only SINGLEPART geometries. it is hard to test this code without your data but this approach will help you need to break down the multipolygons

```
drop table if exists eric_z;
create table eric_z as

with a as(select (st_dump(shape)).geom shape,* 
        from geo_a a
        )
select z.id,
       z.name,
       st_makepolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(st_union(a.shape))) as shape,
       count(*)
from a join geo_z z on a."ZS_id" = z.id
  group by z.id, z.name;

alter table eric_z drop column geom;
```